# Finding a minimum $v$ given $N = d u + s v$, given positive integer $N, d, s$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

We need to find a minimum of $v$ in :

$$N = du + sv$$

where $N, d,s$ are given positive integer, $u$ and $v$ are arbitrary positive integers.

For example, $19 = 5\cdot 2 + 3\cdot 3$ where $d,u,s,v = 5, 2, 3, 3$ resp.

How can we find a minimum of such a $v$, and if it may not exist?

I know very basic modulo properties, but they do not give direct answer.